# Loading text into Div with jQuery with recent jQuery version

Tags: jquery

The following code does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#myText" ).load( "words.txt" );
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="myText">The original text</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am attempting to replace the text in the Div with that from a text file (words.txt). However, if I change the jquery version in the library download from 2.1.3 to 1.11.3, it does work !

So does this method no longer work in recent versions of jQuery? If so, what method should I use to get the same result. I want to use a recent version of jQuery because other parts of the same page need the later functionality.

Any help or advice appreciated. - Mike

Comment: jQuery 2.x does not support older browsers, specifically IE 6, 7 and 8. http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/ in case you are using one of those browsers. This could be part of the problem.

Comment: I'm using IE11 and it doesn't work with that, or with Chrome. However, it does work with Firefox 41.0.2. - Mike